# ecc public key initialization and signature check

Tags: public-key-encryption, public-key

I'm trying to use *Crypto++* to initialize a public key only and use it to verify a signature.

An external chip creates a signature of a message using its private key (K283 aka sect283k1) (invisible for me).
The signature has the format of 72 bytes (36 R and 36 S coordinate) concatinated to a single signature messege.

The public key is available as 72 byte X and Y coordinate. When i use the internal key pair creator in crypto++ , the verification works. But if i try to initialize the public key only, the verification fails.

Does anyone know how to properly initialize an ECC public key in crypto++ ?